# unable to import tweetTokenizer

Tags: python, tokenize, tweets

I tried to import TweetTokenizer but it didn't happen

I tried installing nltk.download(), but the list of packages didn't included any Tokenizer package.

I followed [this](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) which didn't help

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name TweetTokenizer
```

Comment: Maybe you try to install it first?

Comment: but it was no where listed in nltk.download() package

Comment: how to install it?

Comment: _"I tried to import TweetTokenizer but it didn't happen"_ - be more specific. Did you install the package?

Comment: how to install this TweetTokenizer package?

Comment: I tried installing it through nltk.download() but it was not listed anywhere

Comment: this also gave error 
pip install TweetTokenizer
  "Collecting TweetTokenizer
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement TweetTokenizer (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for TweetTokenizer"

Comment: please someone tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your nltk model, and that should work fine